# Test for equality between two discrete distributions with lots of ties

Tags: statistics

My two empirical distributions have the same number $n$ of observations, where $n$ is in the hundreds or thousands.  I can make more observations if I need to.  Each observation is a relatively small integer, often in the range 0-5.  The observations are actually paired: The $k$th observation of each distribution comes from examining the same object in two different ways.

I want to answer questions such as: Can I reject the hypothesis that

- The two distributions have the same mean?
- The two distributions exceed some integer $t$ the same proportion of the time?
- No distribution "beats" the other (where distribution 1 "beating" distribution 2 means that the paired observation in distribution 1 exceeds the observation in distribution 2 more often than the other way round)?

Is there anything better than the sample mean, sample standard variation and a two-sigma confidence interval?

Comment: Why not use a computerized randomisation test? You appear to have a suitably large random sample.

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful.  I was hoping for something computationally inexpensive.  I read a fair amount about the Cucconi test as a better alternative to Kolmogorov-Smirnov, but I think these rank tests will be hard to make sense of in the presence of such massive ties.

Comment: You don't need to use something computationally expensive. Just define a test statistic of your choice and calculate it for each pair. Then you just need an $O(n)$ check to see how significant a given sample is.